# Alternatives to nth-last-of-type and nth-last-child in nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby, css, nokogiri

i'm using nokogiri gem, i want to extract the last number for a pagination (4) with :nth-last-of-type(3) or nth-last-child(3) but show 0 in my ruby test.

```
<ul class="pag">
    <li class="pag-first">first</li>
    <li class="pag-item"><a href"#">2</a></li>
    <li class="pag-item"><a href"#">3</a></li>
    <li class="pag-item"><a href"#">4</a></li>
    <li class="pag-next"><a href"#">next</a></li>
    <li class="pag-last"><a href"#">last</a></li>
</ul>
```

My question is, if exist another alternative to get the last number (4) with another css3 property in nokogiri gem.

My css example is running here: http://jsfiddle.net/kfDgR/

I hope, you can guide me, thk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with `last-child` and `last-of-type`, they don't always mean what you think they do and the specs are ambiguous. I recommend:

```
doc.search('li.pag-item').last
```

Comment: still not all CSS selectors supported by Nokogiri... :) [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/394)

Comment: so.. what if *4* is not last?

Comment: I'm assuming he wants the last `li.pag-item`, not the 4th li. But you're right, the question doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @pguardiario, Babai yes, i want the last li.page-item. I test with:    total_pages = doc.search('li.pag-item').last.text.to_i and this give me the value i want. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Using XPATH is good to go:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-_HTML_
<ul class="pag">
    <li class="pag-first">first</li>
    <li class="pag-item"><a href"#">2</a></li>
    <li class="pag-item"><a href"#">3</a></li>
    <li class="pag-item"><a href"#">4</a></li>
    <li class="pag-next"><a href"#">next</a></li>
    <li class="pag-last"><a href"#">last</a></li>
</ul>
_HTML_

doc.at("//ul[@class = 'pag']/li[4]").text
# => "4"

doc.at("//li[@class='pag-item'][last()]").text
# => "4"
```

Comment: What if it's not the 4th?